# regex to extract citation

Tags: python, regex

Given the following example text, I want to be able to extract the sentences associated to **Citation:**. So for the following text:

```
1. **Fact:** The Tenant is obligated to obtain all consents required by law and provide copies to the Landlord upon request.
   **Citation:** "to obtain all consents which the law requires and give copies to the Landlord on request;" 

2. **Fact:** The Tenant must pay all rates, taxes, and outgoings related to the Property, including any imposed after the date of the Lease.
   **Citation:** "To pay all rates, taxes and outgoings relating to the Property, including any which are imposed after the date of this Lease (even if of a novel nature)."

3. **Fact:** The Tenant is required to pay VAT on any payments made under the Lease and on any payments made by the Landlord that the Tenant agrees to reimburse.
   **Citation:** "To pay VAT on any payment made by the Tenant under this Lease and (except to the extent that the Landlord can reclaim it) on any payment made by the Landlord where the Tenant agrees to reimburse the Landlord
```

I want regex to produce a list of the following:

```
[
"to obtain all consents which the law requires and give copies to the Landlord on request;",
"To pay all rates, taxes and outgoings relating to the Property, including any which are imposed after the date of this Lease (even if of a novel nature).",
"To pay VAT on any payment made by the Tenant under this Lease and (except to the extent that the Landlord can reclaim it) on any payment made by the Landlord where the Tenant agrees to reimburse the Landlord"
]
```

This is my attempt using regex:

```
regex = r"\*\*Citation\:\s*?\"(?P<citation>.*?)\""
citations = re.findall(regex, text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

However all this returns is an empty list. Any help would be great.

Comment: Are those `**` really in the source text?  Your pattern is only expecting one `*` after citation, when in fact there seem to be two of them.

Comment: Note you missed `**` after `Citation` in your regex. See https://regex101.com/r/KgTHN1/1. So if there are really asterisks in the text, just put them in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
import re

text = """
1. **Fact:** The Tenant is obligated to obtain all consents required by law and provide copies to the Landlord upon request.
   **Citation:** "to obtain all consents which the law requires and give copies to the Landlord on request;" 

2. **Fact:** The Tenant must pay all rates, taxes, and outgoings related to the Property, including any imposed after the date of the Lease.
   **Citation:** "To pay all rates, taxes and outgoings relating to the Property, including any which are imposed after the date of this Lease (even if of a novel nature)."

3. **Fact:** The Tenant is required to pay VAT on any payments made under the Lease and on any payments made by the Landlord that the Tenant agrees to reimburse.
   **Citation:** "To pay VAT on any payment made by the Tenant under this Lease and (except to the extent that the Landlord can reclaim it) on any payment made by the Landlord where the Tenant agrees to reimburse the Landlord"
"""

regex = r"\*\*Citation\:\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\n\n|\Z)"
citations = re.findall(regex, text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

print(citations)
```

Output:

```
['** "to obtain all consents which the law requires and give copies to the Landlord on request;"', '** "To pay all rates, taxes and outgoings relating to the Property, including any which are imposed after the date of this Lease (even if of a novel nature)."', '** "To pay VAT on any payment made by the Tenant under this Lease and (except to the extent that the Landlord can reclaim it) on any payment made by the Landlord where the Tenant agrees to reimburse the Landlord"']
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems just as good as anything else:

```
>>> print(text)

1. **Fact:** The Tenant is obligated to obtain all consents required by law and provide copies to the Landlord upon request.
   **Citation:** "to obtain all consents which the law requires and give copies to the Landlord on request;"

2. **Fact:** The Tenant must pay all rates, taxes, and outgoings related to the Property, including any imposed after the date of the Lease.
   **Citation:** "To pay all rates, taxes and outgoings relating to the Property, including any which are imposed after the date of this Lease (even if of a novel nature)."

3. **Fact:** The Tenant is required to pay VAT on any payments made under the Lease and on any payments made by the Landlord that the Tenant agrees to reimburse.
   **Citation:** "To pay VAT on any payment made by the Tenant under this Lease and (except to the extent that the Landlord can reclaim it) on any payment made by the Landlord where the Tenant agrees to reimburse the Landlord"

>>> results = re.findall(r"Citation:\*\*\s\"(.*)\"", text)
>>> for result in results:
...     print(result)
...
to obtain all consents which the law requires and give copies to the Landlord on request;
To pay all rates, taxes and outgoings relating to the Property, including any which are imposed after the date of this Lease (even if of a novel nature).
To pay VAT on any payment made by the Tenant under this Lease and (except to the extent that the Landlord can reclaim it) on any payment made by the Landlord where the Tenant agrees to reimburse the Landlord
>>>
```